# XSLT: how to write redundant xmlns?

Tags: xslt

I need the following output for bizzare system which expects same xmlns declared in parent and child and refuses to work otherwise. I.e that's what expected:

```
<root xmlns="http://something">
  <element xmlns="http://something" />
</root>
```

I can create xmlns in root with

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="root" namespace="http://something">
      <xsl:element name="node" namespace="http://something" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However it doesn't add xmlns into childnode because node's parent has the same xmlns. How to force XSLT to write xmlns disregarding parent?

Comment: If your target system expects a redundant `xmlns` attribute on every element, then it does not really understand XML and it's questionable if it should have been built around "XML" in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

The XML schema specification [expressly prohibits](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-attribute) attributes named `xmlns`, so an XSLT stylesheet [cannot create such attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) directly using `<xsl:attribute>`.  I can only see two options for you...

One option is to create dummy attributes using a different name (e.g. `xmlnsx`):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="root">
      <xsl:attribute name="xmlnsx">http://something</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:element name="node">
          <xsl:attribute name="xmlnsx">http://something</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

... and then replace all occurrences of the attribute `xmlnsx` with `xmlns` in some post-processing step (such as a SAX filter or other stream editor).  However, this solution involves inserting a non-XSLT step into the pipeline.

The other option is pure, if ugly, XSLT.  You could generate the required XML directly, using `xsl:text` and `disable-output-escaping`, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;root xmlns="http://something"&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;node xmlns="http://something"&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/root&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the XSLT 1.0 specification is pretty loose when it comes to serialization, so a particular XSLT processor could still conceivable strip the redundant namespace declarations from this second solution.  However, it worked in the four processors that I tried (namely Saxon, MSXML, MSXML.NET and LIBXML).

Comment: You wrote: *a particular XSLT processor could still conceivable strip the redundant namespace declarations from this second solution*. That's wrong, mostly because there is no redundant namespace declaration in your second solution, just an unescaped text node. Supporting DOE mechanism, **that** could be optional.

Comment: @Alejandro: Agreed.  I was thinking about failure modes in multi-stage pipelines.  This could not occur in a single stage transformation.